# How does lucene proximity search work with multiple out of order words?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, proximity, edit-distance

I'm working in elastic search and have a sentence such as this:

```
"Vet caring dog license cat bird"
```

If I want to search for "bird dog vet" I would need to use at least ~7 as the proximity parameter (`"bird dog vet"~7`). Why is it ~7?